# membrane vibration for an arbitrary initial condition

Tags: classical-field-theory

Consider a membrane with some fixed boundary condition, we can put any initial condition on it, then we let it evolve by the classical equation of motion. 
What will be the final state? some superposition of eigenmodes? assuming there is no dissipation anywhere so that the energy is conserved.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Even_dimensions)?

Answer (score 0):

You will get a linear superposition of an, in general, infinite number eigensolutions corresponding to eigenfrequencies of the 2-dimensional wave equation with the given boundary conditions whose coefficients are determined by the intial conditions at t=0. If there is no damping, the membrane will vibrate indefinitely with this superposition of eigenmodes.